# Old movie where main role reset whole planet earth timeline to the beginning of life on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

The movie should be something about time travel.

I just remember the final scene of the movie. That final scene I remember is:

The main character in the movie turns the machine to get back into time to save (I think) humanity, and it takes him all the way back to the beginning of life on the planet Earth.
It is long before humans and dinosaurs... he actually reset everything.
I actually think that he (I think it was male char in the main role) through a movie with his "team" tries to go back through time more than two times to fix some big disaster to save humanity, or maybe it was just the whole planet Earth.

Maybe I distorted the scene of it in my head, but it should be:
The main character was in some spaceship or it was some satellite, and he argues with some girl from his team. Or just the two of them left of the whole team. I remember them to be in like spacesuits. He decides to make ultimate sacrifice by turn the machine one last time and seemingly destroy it with themselves... but the machine success to make "jump" and... there is the effect of it... the screen turns black and then shows a landscape with some hills, rocks, etc. The sun rises in the background everything, seems red - and the narrator (I think it was a female voice) talks about first life and the creation of it... and the credits roll.

So in the end, there is no more time machine and anyone alive.

I'm not so sure but the movie should be older than 10 years.

That's actually all I can remember. I sadly can't give any more information.

Comment: This sounds like a Doctor Who episode (from the Tom Baker era). I can't remember the name but pretty sure it was written by Douglas Adams and that he re-used some of the ideas in one of his Dirk Gently books. If I can work out the title, I shall return...  (Technically this is not a movie but was a 2 or 3 episode story arc but the description of the end sounds very similar)

Comment: So it was a 4 episode arc apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Death . It actually isn't a great match with your description but a few key points do still align. i.e. the ending and the fact that the main character is indeed trying to repeat certain events and the success/failure of these attempts would influence the start of the current life on earth...

Comment: Similar to saving planet in "A Sound of Thunder" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTmKsKhMcIg

Comment: Not a Sound of Thunder - saw the ending of that movie and that's not the ending I searching for!

Comment: Just read the plot on Wikipedia and the end of it doesn't finish at all with total reset... that's not what I search for!

Comment: Do you remember narrator words? How that time machine looked like? Did MC jump only into the very past, or there were some other jumps?

Comment: Not sure about words. But 100% it was something about life and its creation. The voice maybe was female. Not sure how the machine looks like, but with that question you remind me that they were in some spacesuits. Maybe they were in a spaceship or some satellite and machine was part of it! MC (?) try few times to jump through time with his team to save the whole of humanity (I think) of some big disaster! In the end when he turns the machine last time he seemingly destroys the machine and themselves, but the machine success to make the jump and reset everything to the beginning! Sad but good!

Comment: MC -  main character

Comment: I guess it... 

Comment: A few elements of the description make me think of [Millennium (1989)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)) in that there is a time machine, everything is destroyed at the end, and the final scene (IIRC) is something like a sunrise on a new pristine world, but major plot points are entirely different. In Millennium, agents are sent back in time to extract people from imminent fatal air crashes, replacing them with replica corpses so that the would-be victims can be sent forward in time to populate a new world.

Comment: Found a YouTube of the full Millennium movie; here is a link to the last few minutes to compare with your memory: https://youtu.be/oNfYQ_TOVlQ?t=4395

Comment: Also, Q takes Picard back to the beginning of life on Earth in the final TNG episode.

Comment: @Spencer OP's description does read like a mash-up of Doctor Who: City of Death, TNG: All Good Things and Millennium

Comment: # http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/adam_and_eve

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1ysxom/tomt_sci_fi_film_that_ends_with_the_last_2/

Comment: Anthony X...    It looks like I searched for Millenium (1989)!  Maybe I do not remember things right! I saw the end of Millenium on YouTube and I definitely think that is a movie I search for! Post it as the answer to I mark it!

Comment: Agree this is Millennium, starring 70’s singer/actor heart throb Kris Kristofferson.  The notable part was the relatively memorable end voiceover (which I recall being one of the “future” male characters): “This is not the end. Or even the beginning of the end— …it is the end of the beginning.”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although some of the details don't line up, the ending loosely matches up with the [1989 sci-fi movie Millennium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(film)) starring Kris Kristofferson and Cheryl Ladd.

Cheryl's character Louise Baltimore is one of a team of agents from Earth's future. In her native time, Earth has suffered an environmental disaster in which human life is ending; the remedy involves a time-travel mission to harvest humans from the past and send them forward in time to a presumed far future when the environment has recovered. Louise and her teammates travel back to imminent aircraft crashes, rescuing the passengers from certain death and replacing them with zombie-like replicas. In this way, people can be plucked from the past ostensibly without their disappearance being noticed.

Kris plays an air crash investigator who discovers certain anomalies and has a sequence of encounters with Louise. Daniel J. Travanti appears as a scientist who, as a child, also has an encounter with Louise and/or a teammate, and as an adult, theorizes about time travelers from the future. Louise's inadvertent encounters with Kris's and Daniel's characters lead to an escalating series of paradoxes ("time quakes") in Louise's native time which ultimately trigger the catastrophic destruction of the time machine, everyone, and everything around it.

The movie ends with the rescued passengers being ushered through the time machine into the future, escaping the destruction.

Fun fact: there is a scene in which Cheryl and Kris exit the airport building and get into a car. That scene was filmed in Canada at Toronto International Terminal #1 which no longer exists (it served from the mid 60s thru the early 2000s).

Comment: I saw the ending of the movie on Youtube and it is ending I search for!  About description, I give - most possible I forget it and I made up story different. but millennium is the movie I search for!